# Отзывы в Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть сайт на WP Woocommerce, поставил на него новую тему, после чего в карточке товара отзывы с вкладки (таба) переместились вниз, как их вернуть во вкладку?

Comment: Переверстать тему (дочернюю)

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как именно? Какие изменения нужно ввести в тему чтоб отзывы встали в таб. Плюс еще одна проблема на новой теме, в корзине нету кросселов,а они нужны.